# Bootstrap Sidebar with non-fluid Container

Tags: bootstrap-4

I've been requested to implement something which I think is not really compatible.

A collapsible side-menu (using Bootstrap 4) with a page that is using a `container`. So, NOT `container-fluid`.

It seems to be incompatible, because `container` centers content in the middle of the viewport. Sidebars tend to be hard up against the left edge.

Every example of a Bootstrap sidebar uses `container-fluid`, which further suggests that doing this with `container` is just not practical.

Has anyone seen it done with `container`? And are there any online examples (that I have missed)?

Cheers

Comment: What is your goal exactly? To place a sidebar next to a `.container`? What have you tried so far or do you have a sketch from what it should look like? 
You could remove the auto margin from the `container` to stop centering it.

Comment: @LuukSkeur The kind of menu I am talking about is here - https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar . It shows and hides on toggle.
When the page is full-screen, it is all fine and dandy.
But it does not seem possible to do this when centering your page (as in using `container`).
Personally, I think the two approaches are incompatible.
I've never seen it done, either. But my stakeholders seem to think it is a great idea ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a simple demo. See if that's what you want.

The basic idea is to have `<body>` display as flexbox with row direction, no wrapping, and show/hide the toggler to the sidebar below some breakpoints (because there is not enough space for a sidebar on narrow screens, like below lg-break point).

#### Structure

```html
<body>
    <aside id="sidebar" class="collapse d-lg-block">
        <h2>Brand</h2>
        <nav class="nav flex-column">
            ...
        </nav>
    </aside>
    <main class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light d-block d-lg-none">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#sidebar">
                ...
            </button>
        </nav>

        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        ...
    </main>
</body>
```

#### Styles

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

#sidebar {
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

#### Screenshots

Below large break point:

[image]

Above large break point:

[image]

#### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/Lqvj09da/96/

#### If you're using SASS

There is one more thing I can think of that you can do to make the sidebar take up the most space possible, if you're using SASS.

```css
$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px,
  xxl: 1320px
) !default;
```

I am thinking to set the width of the sidebar as (viewport width - container max width ) / 2:

```css
@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
    #sidebar {
        ...
        width: calc(50vh - map-get($container-max-widths, "lg") / 2);
    }
}
@include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
    #sidebar {
        ...
        width: calc(50vh - map-get($container-max-widths, "xl") / 2);
    }
}
@include media-breakpoint-up(xxl) {
    #sidebar {
        ...
        width: calc(50vh - map-get($container-max-widths, "xxl") / 2);
    }
}
```

This is just an idea. I haven't had a chance to test it yet.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll play around with that tonight. That actually looks like it might be a solution. Cheers.